# Why is HTML rendering as Plain Text in a simple 'title' alteration?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I have been able to change each node's [Comment Link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21comment%21comment.module/function/comment_node_view/7.x) 'title' text (that on default renders 'Add new comment') with the below code, but if I add HTML, it renders as plain text. I'm trying to add a FontAwesome icon before this text `<i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i>`

[image]

```
function MODULE_node_view_alter(&$build) {
  $node = $build['#node'];
  if (isset($build['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add'])) {
    $build['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add']['title'] = '<i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Comment';
  }
}
```

All I have passed is a $build parameter, but I am unsure of whether or not this is the issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render HTML in links by setting the `html` option to `TRUE`.
Check [theme_links()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_links/7.x) to see all options.

For example

```
theme('links', array(
  'links' => array(
    'title' => '<span>Title</span>',
    'href' => 'node/1',
    'html' => FALSE, // default
  )
))
```

would result in the span tag being escaped, while

```
theme('links', array(
  'links' => array(
    'title' => '<span>Title</span>',
    'href' => 'node/1',
    'html' => TRUE,
  )
))
```

would render the span tag as html.

So in your case you need to add the following row.

```
$build['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add']['html] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't include html in that field, as that is the type of field which may need to remain as plain text and translatable, you can use css to prepend the icon.

```css
    a:before {
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        content: "\f086";
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a>Add Comment</a>
```

Comment: Wow, so much easier using CSS & Unicode! Thank you! :)

Comment: The only disadvantage I can find is the lack of hover color on the anchor, as it isn't positioned within the anchor. For now it will do, but I'm still open to hearing any other ideas on how I might be able to do this in PHP.